# Solving $x\left(y^2-z^2\right)u_x-y\left(x^2+z^2\right)u_y+z\left(x^2+y^2\right)u_z=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Or $x\left(y^2-z^2\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-y\left(x^2+z^2\right)\frac{\partial \:u}{\partial \:y}+z\left(x^2+y^2\right)\frac{\partial \:u}{\partial \:z}=0$ if you are not familiar with $u_x$ and such

This is what I have:

$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{dy}{y\left(x^2+z^2\right)}=\frac{dz}{z\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$

$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{-dy}{-y\left(x^2+z^2\right)}=\frac{dz}{z\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$

$$\frac{dx-dy+dz}{x\left(y^2-z^2\right)-y\left(x^2+z^2\right)+z\left(x^2+y^2\right)}=ds$$

$$\frac{dx-dy+dz}{0}=ds$$

$$dx-dy+dz=0$$

The potential I find is $v\left(x,y,z\right)=x-y+z+C_1$ thus:

$$C_1=x-y+z$$

But now I tried to calculate $C_2$ but can't find a proper way to do that

Also, my $C_1$ is apparently wrong, I don't know why, because our teacher said that we can calculate it like that, that we just try to find a potential v(x,y,z) here (I'd be interested why we can do this though because I've applied this technique before and it worked without any problems)

Comment: did you actually try expanding your denominator? It is not zero.

Comment: Ok you're right. Just asking, but why does this method work in the first place? Because our teacher didn't explain that to us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{dy}{y\left(x^2+z^2\right)}=\frac{dz}{z\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$
Mulitply all the fractions by $2$. And the numerator and denominator by $y$ for  the second fraction and by $z$ for the third fraction:
$$\frac{2dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{2ydy}{y^2\left(x^2+z^2\right)}=\frac{2zdz}{z^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$
$$\frac{2dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{dy^2}{y^2\left(x^2+z^2\right)}=\frac{dz^2}{z^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$
$$\frac{2dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{dy^2-z^2}{x^2\left(y^2-z^2\right)}$$
$$2x{dx}={d(y^2-z^2)}$$
$${dx^2}={d(y^2-z^2)}$$
$$x^2-y^2+z^2=C_1$$

---

For the second constant of integration you can use the constant $C_1$
$$\frac{dx}{x\left(y^2-\:z^2\right)}=\frac{dy}{y\left(x^2+z^2\right)}$$
Use the fact that:
$$x^2-y^2+z^2=C_1$$
$$z^2=C_1-(x^2-y^2)$$
Then solve the differential equation.
$$\frac{dx}{x\left(x^2-C_1\right)}=\frac{dy}{y\left(C_1+y^2\right)}$$

Comment: Why is this 2 appearing on the left side?

Comment: Multiply all the fractions by 2 then note that $dy^2=2yfy$ same for $dz^2$ @user

Comment: I added some lines hope its more clear now @user

Comment: Ok I see it thank you

Comment: And how can I calculate $C_2$?

Comment: Uou're very welcome @user

Comment: You can use the constant $C_1$ to get ride of the variable $z$ if you take the first two fractions @user

Comment: I added more lines for the second constant @user

Comment: Thank you very much